# Is it possible to make Android WebView zoom work like Firefox / Chrome zoom?

Tags: android, webview, zooming

It's possible to configure `WebView` on Android to allow zooming as well as to zoom it programmatically, by calling `zoomBy(factor)`, for example.

However, this zooming has the effect of zooming everything, including the viewport itself, which no longer fits in the browser window. So you end up with horizontal scrolling.

In contrast, on (desktop) Firefox and Chrome, when you zoom, a factor is applied to the content, but the viewport is scaled by the inverse factor so that it still takes up the exact "physical" width of your browser window. Thus, if you are viewing a graphic that is 100px x 100px in a viewport/window that is 500px wide, and you zoom to 200%, the graphic is now 200x200, and the viewport is now 250 (virtual) pixels wide, and it still takes up 500 actual pixels in your browser window.

Is there any way to make the Android WebView behave in the same way?